# How to Create Android Virtual Device AVD for Xiaomi , Redmi , Samsung , Huawai etc

Tags: android, kotlin, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

Basically, I want to test my app for Xiaomi, Redmi, Samsung, Huawai, etc like manufacturers.

They make lots of custom tweaks in permission and settings of the ROM, and many frameworks and sensor information some out to be null cause of that.

I will really appreciate any guidance on how you do testing for such platforms and if there is any guide to setup AVDs for Xiaomi, Redmi, Samsung, Huawai, etc please share

Comment: You can try using genymotion for emulator

Comment: Android Studio provides only stock android images for emulators. You might need to get another emulator service or a physical device.

Answer (score 3):

well, you can't do this... manufacturers aren't distribute their system images freely for installing on AVD. you have to get physical device for testing purposes

Comment: is there any hack we can copy their entire os image and then port those images to same spec avds?

Comment: never heard of such possibility, I very doubt it exists, as OS distributed on devices is already compiled and pre-configured for mounted hardware components. Note that on the market you can find companies which are "renting" fleet ("farm"?) of different devices for testing or even spamming purposes. There is even such possibility in Google Play Store console (as far as I remember: your app might be tested on 20 most popular devices worldwide, you are getting report, logs, video etc.)